# UPDATE con INNER JOINS

Tags: mysql, sql, pgadmin

-- Buenas, tengo el siguiente caso: tengo que cambiar el nombre de la columna "referee_code" de la tabla "tb_match", pero sin poder "averiguar" el código del árbitro, solamente con el nombre. Tengo lo siguiente, pero me cambia toda la tabla en vez de sólo la linea que quiero.

```
UPDATE tb_match
SET referee_code = 
      (SELECT referee_code
       FROM tb_referee
       WHERE referee_name = 'Jens Maae')
FROM tb_match AS m
INNER JOIN tb_referee ON m.referee_code = tb_referee.referee_code
INNER JOIN tb_team AS l ON m.home_team_code = l.team_code
INNER JOIN tb_team AS v ON m.visitor_team_code = v.team_code
INNER JOIN tb_country AS lc ON l.country_code = lc.country_code
INNER JOIN tb_country AS vc ON v.country_code = vc.country_code
WHERE tb_referee.referee_name = 'Þorvaldur Árnason'
AND m.match_date = '20210619'
AND (lc.country_name = 'Germany' OR vc.country_name = 'Germany');
```

-- Si hago el select para comprovar que voy a cambiar la linea que quiero me sale correcto:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_match AS m
INNER JOIN tb_referee ON m.referee_code = tb_referee.referee_code
INNER JOIN tb_team AS l ON m.home_team_code = l.team_code
INNER JOIN tb_team AS v ON m.visitor_team_code = v.team_code
INNER JOIN tb_country AS lc ON l.country_code = lc.country_code
INNER JOIN tb_country AS vc ON v.country_code = vc.country_code
WHERE tb_referee.referee_name = 'Þorvaldur Árnason'
AND m.match_date = '20210619'
AND (lc.country_name = 'Germany' OR vc.country_name = 'Germany');
```

Entonces creo que el problema puede estar en la parte del "SET"...
Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

No estoy muy segura porque no puedo probarlo, pero creo que no te funciona porque no indicas en que **referee_code** quieres guardar el dato, es decir, de que tabla. Prueba algo asi:

```
UPDATE m
SET m.referee_code = 
      (SELECT referee_code
       FROM tb_referee
       WHERE referee_name = 'Jens Maae')
FROM tb_match AS m
INNER JOIN tb_referee ON m.referee_code = tb_referee.referee_code
INNER JOIN tb_team AS l ON m.home_team_code = l.team_code
INNER JOIN tb_team AS v ON m.visitor_team_code = v.team_code
INNER JOIN tb_country AS lc ON l.country_code = lc.country_code
INNER JOIN tb_country AS vc ON v.country_code = vc.country_code
WHERE tb_referee.referee_name = 'Þorvaldur Árnason'
AND m.match_date = '20210619'
AND (lc.country_name = 'Germany' OR vc.country_name = 'Germany');
```

Si no te funciona, prueba también sin los alias para verlo más claro.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE m
SET m.referee_code = 
      (SELECT referee_code
       FROM tb_referee
       WHERE referee_name = 'Jens Maae')
FROM tb_match AS m
INNER JOIN tb_referee ON m.referee_code = tb_referee.referee_code
INNER JOIN tb_team AS l ON m.home_team_code = l.team_code
INNER JOIN tb_team AS v ON m.visitor_team_code = v.team_code
INNER JOIN tb_country AS lc ON l.country_code = lc.country_code
INNER JOIN tb_country AS vc ON v.country_code = vc.country_code
WHERE tb_referee.referee_name = 'Þorvaldur Árnason'
AND m.match_date = '20210619'
AND (lc.country_name = 'Germany' OR vc.country_name = 'Germany');
```

Tu problema es que llamaste a la tabla tb_match como "**m**" y en el `UPDATE` sigues llamándola como antes, por lo que no hace nada.

Comment: Buenas, si hago lo que me indicas me salta ERROR: NO EXISTE LA RELACIÓN "m".

Comment: El hecho es que me cambia todas las lineas, no es que no haga nada. Gracias